# take photo with webrtc

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

On My chrome the following code just opens up the camera and immediately crashes i.e show black screen. This code works fine on firefox. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/2mLb6cs2/

```
(function() {
    // The width and height of the captured photo. We will set the
    // width to the value defined here, but the height will be
    // calculated based on the aspect ratio of the input stream.

    var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
    var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream

    // |streaming| indicates whether or not we're currently streaming
    // video from the camera. Obviously, we start at false.

    var streaming = false;

    // The various HTML elements we need to configure or control. These
    // will be set by the startup() function.

    var video = null;
    var canvas = null;
    var photo = null;
    var startbutton = null;

    function startup() {
        video = document.getElementById('takephoto-video');
        canvas = document.getElementById('takephoto-canvas');
        photo = document.getElementById('takephoto-preview');
        previewarea = document.getElementById('takephoto-previewarea');
        startbutton = document.getElementById('takephoto-startbutton');
        downloadbutton = document.getElementById('takephoto-download');

        navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia);

        navigator.getMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            },
            function(stream) {
                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }
                video.play();
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("An error occured! " + err);
            }
        );

        video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
            if (!streaming) {
                height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

                // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
                // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.

                if (isNaN(height)) {
                    height = width / (4 / 3);
                }

                video.setAttribute('width', width);
                video.setAttribute('height', height);
                canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                streaming = true;
            }
        }, false);

        startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            takepicture();
            ev.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        clearphoto();
    }

    // Fill the photo with an indication that none has been
    // captured.

    function clearphoto() {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    }

    // Capture a photo by fetching the current contents of the video
    // and drawing it into a canvas, then converting that to a PNG
    // format data URL. By drawing it on an offscreen canvas and then
    // drawing that to the screen, we can change its size and/or apply
    // other changes before drawing it.

    function takepicture() {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (width && height) {
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            photo.setAttribute('src', data);

            previewarea.classList.remove("hide");
            downloadbutton.href = data;

        } else {
            clearphoto();
        }
    }

    startup();
})();
```

Above code is copied from

https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-capturestill/

Comment: try with https: https://jsfiddle.net/2mLb6cs2/

Comment: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you open console on jsfiddle page, you will see the following error:

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this
>   feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure
>   origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

If you try to use it with https, it works.

Why it works in FireFox with http? Probably because it was deprecated only in Chrome at this moment, but anyway you should use https, using WebRTC.

BTW, I see you use browser prefixes in your code. It's better to use [adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) [instead](https://github.com/webrtc/samples):

> All of the samples use adapter.js, a shim to insulate apps from spec
>   changes and prefix differences. In fact, the standards and protocols
>   used for WebRTC implementations are highly stable, and there are only
>   a few prefixed names. For full interop information, see
>   webrtc.org/web-apis/interop.

Comment: thought so. can i test with https anywhere. jsfiddle is http only